# Launching Node.js app on OpsWorks

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm having trouble getting my OpsWorks custom recipe to launch my node application. I'm just starting to learn the fundamentals of Chef, so I may be missing something rather obvious.

To get me started I forked a copy of [AWS nodejs cookbook](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_nodejs) and made very minor changes. I was also sure to copy the node deploy script [here](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/deploy/recipes).

My layers are now fully configured and I can trigger node manually via SSH, however it seems that upon deploy it's not triggered by the Ruby script.

I'm assuming the start program line (which is the only place in the cookbook where I can see node being started) isn't getting run:

```
check host node_web_app_<%= @application_name %> with address 127.0.0.1
  start program = "/bin/bash -c 'cd <%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current; source <%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/shared/app.env; /usr/bin/env PORT=<%= @deploy[:nodejs][:port] %> NODE_PATH=<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current/node_modules:<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/current /usr/local/bin/node <%= @monitored_script %>' --NODE_ENV=prod"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/pkill -f 'node <%= @monitored_script %>'"
  <% if @deploy[:ssl_support] -%>
  if failed port <%= @deploy[:nodejs][:port] %> type TCPSSL protocol HTTP
  <% else -%>
  if failed port <%= @deploy[:nodejs][:port] %> protocol HTTP
  <% end -%>
    request /
    with timeout 10 seconds
    then restart
```

So I'm really at a loss for why it's not doing it's thing.

It almost seems as though this deploy cookbook wasn't fully completed. If there's a better cookbook available that someone can suggests, I'd consider changing.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to set Opsworks env variables in the app configuration. These variables then get loaded via `<%= @deploy[:deploy_to] %>/shared/app.env` There is no need to set your env variable in this script directly.

Comment: Thanks @Yousef. I found out that you can override it by changing your Custom JSON to { deploy: { app_name: { environment_variables: { //put them here } } } however it doesn't seem to be working. I can't even find a sample Custom JSON that overrides it and the documentation is SO underwhelming. This is making me hate OpsWorks.

Comment: Go to your stack --> click 'Apps' --> Navigate to your app and hit 'Edit' and then you should see 'Environment Variables' section with key/value inputs. Try that and let me know, otherwise I'll add screenshots. Once you get the hang of it, you'll actually appreciate opsworks.

Comment: Oh, I thought it had to be in the Custom JSON values. That's great if I can inject them directly. So you're saying if I put monitored_script in those variables it will take effect? Great.

Comment: I guess the next thing I need to determine is how can I deploy a specific app to a specific layer! Once I resolve that, everything should work perfectly.

Comment: are you using nodejs layer?

Comment: I am indeed. You should submit an answer so I can select your response and up vote it @Yousuf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the AWS opsworks nodejs layer, you should be able to set environment variables during App registration. You should see a section like this:

[image]

under app settings:

[image]

Where you can set all your variables to be included in the deployment.